Node Js Backend, Database Queries Causing Memory Leak
I have a backend written in NodeJs. I am using a postgreSQL database. I am using docker to run containers. There is a problem I am encountering that the memory consumption of the backend container increases over time and I have narrowed down the cause to read/write operations to the database.
Here is a sniplet of an example database read function. All the others are written the same way.
I couldnt come up with a reason as to why this is happening.
Any input would be appriciated
Thanks in advance.
async getAllUsers() {
    const client = await pool.connect(); // Acquire a client from the pool
    const query = `
      SELECT * FROM Users;
    `;
  
    try {
      const queryResult = await client.query(query);
      console.log(queryResult.rows); // Log all users
      return queryResult.rows; // Return all users for further processing
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error executing select query", err.stack);
      throw err; // Rethrow the error to handle it in the caller function
    } finally {
      client.release(); // Release the client back to the pool
    }
  }

Tried solving the memory leak by adding client.release. Doesnt change the behaviour. The backend memory consumption shouldnt increase over time.

Is there anything specific to Docker in this setup?  Do you see the same behavior if you run the Node application using a plain non-container Node environment?

Did you check pool's props related to clients it provides?
